# Model a kind that reference to itself in google appengine datastore?

Tags: google-app-engine, model, google-cloud-datastore

I have a model Comments. I want to implement a function that user can comment a comment, and I think it's a one-to-many relation, you know, one comment can have some comments. Then I put

`comments = db.ReferenceProperty(Comments,collection_name="comments",required=False)`

into my Comments model, but it doesn't work.

Can a model reference to itself in google appengine datastore? Is there any other hint?

Thank you!

Comment: You might consider using ndb instead of db, since db seems to be kinda outdated.

Comment: @daemonfire300 It's the first time I hear about ndb. Actually, it is not too long since I first hearded about db.Thank you, I will google it. :)

Comment: well I basically made the fault to use Pyhton 2.7 with webapp2, and use db, when I first tried to link webapp2 models like User with db.Models the system went crazy.
Because webapp2 uses n(ew)db and I used the (old) db framework.
ndb makes many things a lot easier since, you have less ndb Property types.
But it's still an effort to switch if you have an existing system

Comment: @daemonfire300 You can link between old and new models by using the nds function `.key.to_old_key()` that con convert between old and new keys. Check out the ndb cheat sheet that guido wrote and you will like the ndb library but you can still use the db model and connect those to ndb models but you can't mix same entity for different libraries i.e. if you have a User entity that is ndb you can't save I User object that is db to that table since the keys are different types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`db.SelfReferenceProperty`](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/typesandpropertyclasses#SelfReferenceProperty) to model a reference to another instance of the same kind.

Answer (score 3):

Use `db.ListProperty(db.Key)` for referencing multiple entities as a property.

Comment: It works, but I don't think it's the best way. If I can use Reference stuff, then using the colection_name will simplify the iteration.

Comment: There is no ListReferenceProperty, see a similar question here: stackoverflow.com/questions/4719700/list-of-references-in-google-app-engine-for-python

Comment: Thank you, I decide to use SelfReferenceProperty.

Comment: You can only reference 1 entity using SelfReferenceProperty

Comment: I use `db.ListProperty(db.Key)` to reference multiple entities and it works but I think this makes my modelling not be in 1NF and not normalized since the variable is a set instead of atomic.